# Code-analyst which params show cache misses?

Tags: c++, windows, profiling

I need to know which parts of my code make the most cache misses.. suggest which parameters of the profiling report I need to monitor, there are too many of them there ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The [AMD documentation](http://www.amddevcentral.com/Assets/Basic_Performance_Measurements.pdf) appears to have good information on this.  See section 4.3.  There are brief examples in sections 5.3 and 5.4.